# How can I show data from Datatables with Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm stuck with datatables and the plugin yajrabox for Laravel 5.4. The goal is to load with ajax and the plugin the data from the users tables in my database, but it just shows me this error :

```
DataTables warning: table id=listingUsers - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.
```

I can't find out where it's coming from and i'm not sure I wrote the code right..

Here is my code.

Controller :

```
 public function index() {
    $users = User::latest()->count();

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}

 public function ajaxListing() {
    $users = User::select(['id', 'username', 'email']);
        return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}
```

Routes :

```
Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UsersController');
Route::any('user-data', 'Admin\UsersController@ajaxListing')->name('datatables.data');
```

View : `

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="listingUsers">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#listingUsers').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
            columns: [
                {data: 0, name: 'id'},
                {data: 1, name: 'name'},
                {data: 2, name: 'email'}
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
@endpush`
```

WHen i'm searching the error in the console and the network the data comes right but just doesn't show in the table.

Can someone tell me what t'im doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: What data do you receive in the ajax call?

Comment: i'm getting this : 
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 1, recordsFiltered: 1,…}
data
:
[{id: "1", username: "Alex", email: "someadress@example.com"}]
0
:
{id: "1", username: "Alex", email: "someadress@example.com"}
draw
:
1
input
:
{draw: "1", columns: [,…], order: [{column: "0", dir: "asc"}], start: "0", length: "10",…}
queries
:
[,…]
0
:
{query: "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `users`) count_row_table",…}
1
:
{query: "select `id`, `username`, `email` from `users` order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0",…}
recordsFiltered
:
1
recordsTotal
:
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data`, you need to specify the column name, like that:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
    {data: 'username', name: 'username'},
    {data: 'email, name: 'email'}
]
```

Comment: it worked like a charm, thanks ! How is that we need to specify the column name like that ?

Comment: `data` must match what you send from your controller, but i'm not sure to know what the `name` stands for, since it still works without. Here's the doc just in case:  https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter